# Custom dependency property isn't getting binded input

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm creating a UserControl with a DependencyProperty but the DependencyProperty isn't getting the value that the caller is passing in.

I've discovered the following during my own investigation

- If I use a built-in user control, such as TextBlock, everything works. This narrows the problem down to my UserControl's implementation (as opposed to the code that calls the UserControl)
- My property changed callback that I register isn't even being called (well... at least the breakpoint isn't being hit)
- If only see this problem when I use a binding to provide the dependency property, so **this doesn't work**:

  ```
  <common:MyUserControl MyDP="{Binding MyValue}"/>
  ```

  but I have no problems if I get rid of the binding and hardcode the value, so **this works**:

  ```
  <common:MyUserControl MyDP="hardCodedValue"/>
  ```

**Here's my UserControl's code behind:**

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string MyDP
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyDPProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyDPProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDPProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MyDP", 
            typeof(string), 
            typeof(MyUserControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                "this is the default value",
                new PropertyChangedCallback(MyUserControl.MyDPPropertyChanged)));

    public static void MyDPPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MyUserControl)obj).MyDP = (string)e.NewValue;
    }

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

**And here's the xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDP}"/>
</Grid>
```

**Since I'm able to use built-in user controls such as TextBlock, I don't think that the error lies in my host code, but here it is, just so that you have a complete picture:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <common:MyUserControl MyDP="{Binding MyValue}"/>
</StackPanel>

public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public string MyValue { get { return "this is the real value."; } }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in the UserControl is wrong:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

This makes the UserControl its own DataContext, so the binding is looking for a property called MyValue on the UserControl, and that property does not exist. You want the DataContext to be your view-model. If you don't set it explicitly, it will inherit the DataContext from its container (the Window in this case).

Delete that line, and you'll be closer. You also don't need that callback; remove that too.

Comment: Removing that line looked like it helped! My MyDPPropertyChanged method is finally being called, and with the correct data-binded value also. Thank you, this got me closer. 

I'm still having problems though - The UI doesn't seem to get updated with the new value. Any ideas? I tried AffectsRender = true, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I also tried removing the callback as you suggested, and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @vivekmaharajh I'd need to see some XAML for the UserControl to help with that aspect.

Comment: The xaml is quite simple:

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDP}"/>
    </Grid>

The problem is that now the view isn't bound to the control, so "MyDP" doesn't mean anything. 

You mentioned that the control now inherits the datacontext of the parent. If I edit the above xaml to bind to "MyValue" instead, everything works. However, this doesn't really sit well, since the UserControl shouldn't have to know the names of the properties of the host's view-model. In fact, I bind properties of all names to the Text property of TextBlocks, and they all work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your control's view code like that:

```
 <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="_textBlock"/>
    </Grid>
```

And set a _textBlock's text property in MyDPPropertyChanged method:

```
public static void MyDPPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = ((MyUserControl)obj);
        control.MyDP = (string)e.NewValue;
        control._textBlock.Text = control.MyDP;
    }
```

That will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, this did indeed "do the trick". 
I wish I could mark both this answer and @Jay's as answers as they both solved different problems that I have, but SO won't let me, but at least it'll let me upvote it.

Comment: In my experience dependency properties were used solely for tuning the behaviour of a component. All data binding was handled via exposing properties of control's viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and PropertyChangedEventHandler  in side the control and also the viewmodel. secondly use SetCurrentValue method to set the value inside the control class rather setting it directly

Comment: Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged didn't make a difference - Note that I'm able to use my view and view model with other built-in controls such as <TextBlock>, and pass my value into its dependency properties such as Text={Binding myValue}, so I'm pretty sure there isn't a problem with the view model.

Also, the Setter for "MyDP" does indeed call "SetValue", so that shouldn't be a problem.